# Azure Service Bus SendAsync not sending message in console app

Tags: azure, asynchronous, queue, servicebus

```
 For some reason, I cannot send the message to the Service Bus Queue in my web job. Is this a limitation of a webjob that I cannot send an async request? I've tried downgrading and upgrading all the packages and even changing the .net framework, but nothing works.
```

Specs: 
1. net framework 4.6.1
2. Microsoft.Azure.Amqp 2.4.3
3. Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 4.1.1
4. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 2.2.0
5. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core 2.2.0
6. Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3
7. WindowsAzure.Storage 9.3.3

Code:

```
 public bool AddoQueue(string message)
        {
            _sendMessage.SendMessageToQueue(message);
            return true;
        }



        static IQueueClient queueClient;

public async Task<bool> SendMessageToQueue(string message)
        {
            try
            {
                queueClient = new QueueClient(Configurator.GetConfigSettings("SBConnectionString"), Configurator.GetConfigSettings("QueueName"));

                var messageObj = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message))
                {
                    TimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(6),
                    PartitionKey = message
                };

                await queueClient.SendAsync(messageObj);

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write(e);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `SendMessageToQueue` is an `async` function, you will need to wait for it to finish.

One possible solution is to change the following line of code:

```
_sendMessage.SendMessageToQueue(message);
```

to

```
_sendMessage.SendMessageToQueue(message).GetAwaiter().GetResult();;
```

Other solution would be to make the calling method `AddoQueue()` as async (and all other methods which call this async as well. In that case your code would be

```
await _sendMessage.SendMessageToQueue(message);
```

Comment: Yes! It worked! Thank you so much! I now see my message on the queue. I tried the first solution, _sendMessage.SendMessageToQueue(message).GetAwaiter().GetResult();